# Adding specific map methods to collections / functors

Tags: scala, functor

So I have a Vec2 class:

```
class Vec2(val x: Double, val y: Double)
{
  def +(other: Vec2): Vec2 = Vec2(x + other.x, y + other.y)   
  def -(other: Vec2): Vec2 = Vec2(x - other.x, y - other.y)
  def *(factor: Double): Vec2 = Vec2(x * factor, y * factor)
  def /(divisor: Double): Vec2 = Vec2(x / divisor, y / divisor)
  //Other methods omitted but you get the idea
}
```

I use this class a lot and I use it a lot in collections, so I would like short hand methods for .map(_ + other) .map(_ * factor) etc. I also want to add methods for addMultAll(second: Vec2, factor: Double) and multAddAll(factor: Double, second: Vec2) that I think would be clearer and safer as explicit methods.

So I chose the traversable class for my implicit. Is this the best / most general class that I can use? I have cribbed and modifed the map method from the scala source code. Is the code below correct? Will it work without problems?

```
object Vec2
{   
  import collection.mutable.{ Builder }
  import scala.collection._
  implicit class ImpVec2Class[+Repr](travLike: TraversableLike[Vec2, Repr])
  {
    def +++ [That](offset: Vec2)(implicit bf: generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr, Vec2, That]): That =
    {
       def builder =
       { // extracted to keep method size under 35 bytes, so that it can be JIT-inlined
          val b = bf(travLike.repr)
          b.sizeHint(travLike)
          b
       }
       val b = builder
       for (x <- travLike) b += x + offset
       b.result
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to do this for the map methods on Double if I want shortened methods, or does Scalaz / CATS already include them?

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm going to post this as answer as its a slight improvement. I've removed the [That] type parameter on the method. I've also added an implict for Array[Vec2] as Array doesn't inherit from the Scala collection traits.

```
object Vec2
{   
  import collection.mutable.{ Builder }
  import scala.collection._
  implicit class ImpVec2Traversible[Repr](travLike: TraversableLike[Vec2, Repr])
  {
    def +++ (offset: Vec2)(implicit bf: generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr, Vec2, Repr]): Repr =
    {
     def builder =
     { // extracted to keep method size under 35 bytes, so that it can be JIT-inlined
        val b = bf(travLike.repr)
        b.sizeHint(travLike)
        b
     }
     val b = builder
     for (x <- travLike) b += x + offset
     b.result
  }
}
  implicit class ImpVec2Array(arr: Array[Vec2])
  {
    def +++ (offset: Vec2): Array[Vec2] = arr.map(_ + offset)
  }
}
```